# Get an UIImage from URL to iPhone and iPhone retina

Tags: iphone, uiimage, retina-display

I'm trying to get an image from a URL to view it on an iPhone and an iPhone Retina. 
The problem is that iPhone is displayed correctly but Retina is blurred. 
The image has a size of 100x100 at 326dpi (size retina).

I'm doing it correctly?

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    double scaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s419999211.mialojamiento.es/img/bola.png"];

    if (scaleFactor == 2){
        // @2x
        NSLog(@"Estoy cargando la imágen retina");
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        NSLog(@"Width: %f Height: %f",image.size.width,image.size.height);
        yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    } else {
        // @1x
        NSLog(@"Estoy cargando la imágen normal");
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        imagenScalada = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        NSLog(@"Width: %f Height: %f",imagenScalada.size.width,imagenScalada.size.height);
        yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imagenScalada];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:yourImageView];
}
```

[image: Image for normal screen]
[image: Imagen blurred]

Thank you!

iPhone Normal
iPhone Retina

Answer (score 0):

where u notify to server that give me a double size image for retina. If 100x100 image for normal iphone than it should be double in size for retina; If u same image image will blurred.

try this code for determine retina screen

```
  + (BOOL)isRetineDisplay{
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
            ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0)) {
            // Retina display
            return YES;
        } else {
            // not Retine display
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The image is 100x100 for Retina.
Then for iPhone normal, should be 50x50 not?
So I try to scale it to normal size (50x50), but does not work ... My actuality code, shows when you run in normal screen and when you run in retina screen...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    double scaleFactor = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s419999211.mialojamiento.es/img/bola@2x.png"];
    NSData * imageData = nil;
    if (scaleFactor == 2){
        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2x];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
    else {
        imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL2x];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        image = [self scaledImage:image];
    }



    yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:yourImageView];
}


- (UIImage *)scaledImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight); //Change the size of the image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! At first, I did what you said and it works.
I want to avoid having two images on the server. This was only a test, but in the future will have many images and can be very uncomfortable.
So my intention is to produce a single image and scale it.

Comment: You can store a retina image on the server. Download the image and convert it to small size

Comment: Exactly! that's what I'm trying ...
It does not work.
The steps I perform are the following:
1) I check if normal screen or retina with an if / else
2) Release the retinal image in the server, if is retina display, show the image downloaded. But if normal screen, change its size with imagenScalada = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: [image CGImage] scale: 1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];

Then run the application with normal screen and the image became small (seems to work) but if I run the simulator in the retina, the image is blurred

Comment: This are the sizes of the images http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html